# Change Variable over Time Interval in Audio Callback

Tags: objective-c, time, callback, core-audio

so I wanted to change my variable within my for loop over a time interval. In my code, I have my audio callback basically running the following pseudocode:

```
int start = 0, target = 100;
for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++) {
    [object makeSineWave];
    [object useNum:start];
    if (target > start) {
        // Increase start over the span of time frame
    }
}
```

What I want to do is increase start to the target value over a logarithmic scale within a time interval (lets say 1 second to keep it simple). How would I keep track of time within the for loop of the audio callback?

EDIT: Guess I'm trying to make a filter sweep... I'm guessing it'd be similar to a sine sweep now that I think about it? more code-

```
OSStatus RenderTone(void *inRefCon,
                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp,
                UInt32 inBusNumber,
                UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                AudioBufferList *ioData) {
    // Get Audio Data
    AudioData *data = (__bridge AudioData *)inRefCon;
    static Float32 phs = 0, sub_phs = 0;
    Float32 freq = data->freq;
    // Calculate phases
    Float32 phs_incr = 2 * M_PI * freq / data->srate;
    Float32 sample;

    // Buffers
    Float32 *bufL = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[0].mData;
    Float32 *bufR = (Float32 *)ioData->mBuffers[1].mData;

    // Start at 1 hz, target is 500 hz
    int start = 1, target = 500;

    // Generate Samples
    for (UInt32 i = 0; i < inNumberFrames; i++) {
        // Sine waveform
        sample = sinf(phs);
        sample = [data->filter processFilter:sample fc:start];

        // change start here using current time?
        // should not increase to target immediately, over span of 1 second

        bufL[i] = buf[R] = sample;

        // Increment phase
        phs += phs_incr;
        // Wrap phase
        phs = wrapPhase(phs);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the entire callback function?

Comment: @AndrewMadsen there ya go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I found out how to do it through looking at CCRMA's STK... great resource that I wish I found earlier!

https://ccrma.stanford.edu/software/stk/